# UiNavigationBar Back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Is it a good practice to override the UINavigationController back button behavior. 
What does apple say about that. Can some will give some apple developer link about this.what does apple say about that?

Comment: Without linking to whatever Apple feels about it, I would say: NO, not a good pratice; it's a bad practice even. Users expect the backbutton to behave a certain way: take them back one screen in the navigation-stack. Changing that is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding a UINavigationController's back button is not a good approach until it is very necessary. Also if it was not meant to be done, Apple would not have provided with such an option. So, if its necessary there is nothing wrong in overriding a navigation controller's back button but if there is any other option that must be preferred.